# How do I tell if an android activity is finished from an external adb command?

Tags: android, shell, android-activity, adb

In our testing, I want to use a script to run a number of android activities.  I can use an adb shell start activity command to start these activities.  Is there a way, using an adb command, to tell when an activity finishes?  The script needs to know when the first activity is done before issuing the next adb start activity command.

Comment: Why don't you print something out in the activity's `onDestroy` method and have the script be waiting for this log? Not too familiar with adb scripting though...

Answer (score 4):

I did something recently where I wanted a bash script to run an adb command and show/wait until it was finished. This is what worked for me:

```
./adb shell am start -W -n com.android.settings/.ApplicationSettings
```

The script then waited for the applications menu to load before continuing. Not sure how this would work for a longer process but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the source of the applications you are monitoring, do what Daniel has suggested in the comments to the question. But if you can't - try executing `dumpsys activity activities` and see if you could find the info you are looking for there. Take a look at the `Running activities` section and see if your activity disappears from the list when finished.