# Is it possible to start activity through adb shell and receive its response?

Tags: android, shell, android-activity, activity-manager

I know that you can **start any exported activity from any app** via `adb` using the following command:

```
am start -n com.myapp.test/.TestActivity
```

Using the `"am start"` command it is also possible to send extra data to the activity (I know how to do this, this is not the question I am asking here!).

**However what I need to know is if it is also possible to receive the response data sent back from the started activity when it finishes?**

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
You could print results to logcat.
Just start with `-W`, so it waits for launch to complete

and then do a `logcat -d`

**OP already has understanding for the following. I misread the question, keeping it just in case for somebody else who lands here**

To send data to the activity
Please refer [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#shellcommands) for the intent specification.

You can pass in key value pairs.

To Quote from spec
`-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>`    can be used to pass key string-value pair.
There are other options to pass in different type of data

Comment: That was not a question, just a statement. I know how to do it.

Comment: @Robert: My bad man, I read "is it" instead of "it is". Honest mistake :D

Comment: @Robert: Please check the update.

Comment: Nice idea. I tested it with an self-written test app. Unfortunately it does not work because `-W`only waits until the new Activity has been started (not ended). Therefore the `am`process is long gone when the activity ends (by a button click). Also in logcat I do not see the activity result (unless I print it out in my test app).

Comment: @Robert: mmm.. yes, you would need to print it out explicitly to log and parse it out of there. Second, I think the activity would keep on writing to the logcat as it goes on. its just you need to check when the activity has finished.

You could do something like: In the script, start the activity with `am start`. In your activity, in `onDestroy` output to log for example `finished`, then take the log between start and this string and parse for results.. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715560/how-do-i-tell-if-an-android-activity-is-finished-from-an-external-adb-command

Comment: Ok, my example wasn't clear - my aim is starting an activity of a foreign app I don't have the source code. Otherwise I wouldn't had to use `am` for starting the activity. As I want to start a non-exported activity I have to use `su` and `am`.

Answer (score 0):

A roundabout solution：

1,Write a tool-apk that can receive `intent parameters`, and use this parameters to `startActivityForResult`. when get the result, logcat it or write it to some file.

2, use adb to start this tool-apk use any `intent parameters` you want, than,periodically check the logcat or the file to get the result.